# Give different Boost to queries under an OR condition filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to give a different boost to queries in an OR condition filter??? I will want to see the results that match with the first query over the ones that match the second query.

This is part of my query:

```
 {
               "or": [
                            {
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "query": "(field_state:ALL OR field_state:'WA') AND type:incentive"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "query": "* AND NOT (type:adcampaign OR type:incentive OR type:page_simple OR type:page OR type:glossary_item OR type:product OR type:lighting_option)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the ES docs here (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/), yes you can. `boost` is a listed option for the `query_string` query type.

While untested, I imagine something like this will do the trick:

```
{
    "or": [
        {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "(field_state:ALL OR field_state:'WA') AND type:incentive",
                    "boost": 10.5
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "* AND NOT (type:adcampaign OR type:incentive OR type:page_simple OR type:page OR type:glossary_item OR type:product OR type:lighting_option)"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I already try adding the boost on the query_string without any luck, not sure if its because the whole OR is inside a filtered query. so i end up using a custom_filters_score, add my query inside this , add a copule of filters to boost them, and works ok. Thanks for the answer